# Dependency Caching in Gitlab CI based on the SHA1 of my dependencies list

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I'm using Gitlab CI to do linting and testing work in a PHP application and most of the time is taken by Composer installing packages.

Because we have several pipelines per hour, this amounted to a huge amount of bandwidth (and time) lost to composer just downloading a lot of code from everywhere.

We started looking into depedency caching in gitlab ci, but its still usually just downloading the same things over and over. Is there a way to share the caches between pipelines based on the hash of the composer.lock?

We're running DigitalOcean's One-click gitlab server.

We have already tried using these setups but no luck.

```
variables:
  COMPOSER_CACHE_SHA1: "sha1sum composer.lock"

cache:
  key: "eval $COMPOSER_CACHE_SHA1"
```

```
variables:
  COMPOSER_CACHE_SHA1: sha1sum composer.lock

# Cache libraries in between jobs
cache:
  key: "$COMPOSER_CACHE_SHA1"
```

```
cache:
  key: "$(sha1sum composer.lock)"
```

Everything we tried above just caches using a variation of the command instead of the output of the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while of searching, I decided on writing my own implementation of this using a network-based readonly content adressable file system. To prevent this answer from being flagged as self-advertising, full disclosure: I will solve this as a seperate application and Merge-requests welcome. I'll add the link if someone is interested.

Comment: Hello @tvanriel, I am interested in. Do you have any updates?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 1):

Gitlab CI has such option, it is called cache:key:files
Introduced in GitLab v12.5.
See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#cachekey

> The cache:key:files keyword extends the cache:key functionality by
> making it easier to reuse some caches, and rebuild them less often,
> which speeds up subsequent pipeline runs.
>
> When you include cache:key:files, you must also list the project files
> that are used to generate the key, up to a maximum of two files. The
> cache key is a SHA checksum computed from the most recent commits (up
> to two, if two files are listed) that changed the given files. If
> neither file was changed in any commits, the fallback key is default.

```
cache:
  key:
    files:
      - composer.lock
  paths:
    - vendor/
```

Comment: That's nice! And there even is [`cache:key:prefix`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#cachekeyprefix) if you additionally to the file checksums want to get the branch name or step name in.